# Spark Scala Grep Utility

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have around 700 Avro files, each of around 2gb. I have to grep a unix id like '129384755' from these avro files and need to get the avro file name where this id is found.

As Unix grep takes a lot of time, I tried to wrote down a spark scala code for the same, below is my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkGrep {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.err.println("Usage: SparkGrep <host> <input_file> <match_term>")
            System.exit(1)
        }
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkGrep").setMaster(args(0))
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val inputFile = sc.textFile(args(1), 2).cache()
        val matchTerm : String = args(2)
        val numMatches = inputFile.filter(line => line.contains(matchTerm)).count()
        println("%s lines in %s contain %s".format(numMatches, args(1), matchTerm))
        System.exit(0)
    }
}
```

But the issue I am getting is

I ran this code on 700 files giving argument(2) as ////.avro . I want the output as 4 lines in ////part-123.avro contain my id '129384755' . but instead of that I am getting output as '4 lines in ////.avro contain' how I will get to know the File Name out of this 700 files where my search variable (its unique and will be in one file only out of 700 files) is . Can you please help me out here. Will really be helpful from your end.

Comment: Updated the question..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/676782/mehrez can you help me out here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3158463/kang can you help me with this

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems with your question. You have phrased it in a very confusing manner. Please do a better job next time.

"I ran this code on 700 files": I assume it means args(1) is a path of a directory with files with a wildcard

There are multiple ways to do it in spark. If you want to stick to RDDs, the files would have to be small. maybe a couple of 1000s of lines. this would be the approach, below is my spark-shell output:

```
scala> val matchTerm = ".txt"
matchTerm: String = .txt

scala> val fileNames = "/testFolder/*". //path to the directory where the files are
fileNames: String = /testFolder/*

scala>  val inputFile = sc.wholeTextFiles(fileNames)
inputFile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = /Users/vipulrajan/Downloads/testFolder/* MapPartitionsRDD[28] at wholeTextFiles at <console>:26

scala> val fileCounts = inputFile.map{ case (a,b) => { val lines = b.split("\n"); (a, lines.filter(_.contains(matchTerm)).length) }}
fileCounts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[29] at map at <console>:27

scala> fileCounts.foreach(x => println("file %s contains %s lines with the term %s".format(x._1, x._2, matchTerm)))
```

The output would be as follows:

```
file /testFolder/testFile.txt contains 10 lines with the term .txt
file /testFolder/testFile2.txt contains 5 lines with the term .txt
```

I would recommend however that you use DataFrames instead:

```
scala> val fileNames = "/testFolder/*"
fileNames: String = /testFolder/*

scala> val matchTerm = ".txt"
matchTerm: String = .txt

scala> val df = spark.read.text(fileNames).withColumn("inputFile", input_file_name)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, inputFile: string]

scala> df.filter( col("value").contains(matchTerm)).groupBy("inputFile").count.show(false)
```

The output would look as follows:

```
+--------------------------+-----+
|inputFile                 |count|
+--------------------------+-----+
|/testFolder/testFile.txt  |10   |
|/testFolder/testFile2.txt |5    |
+--------------------------+-----+
```

both files, testFile.txt and testFile2.txt are in the directory /testFoler

These are the contents of these files:

testFile.txt

```
fileNosomeb233136.txt
fileNosomeb7559.txt
fileNosomeb340542.txt
fileNosomeb457514.txt
fileNosomeb491638.txt
fileNosomeb27417.txt
fileNosomeb310232.txt
ssamefileNo74582.txt
fileNosomeb77367.txt
fileNosomeb407264.txt
```

testFile2.txt

```
fileNosomeb233136.txt
fileNosomeb7559.txt
fileNosomeb340542.txt
fileNosomeb457514.txt
fileNosomeb491638.txt
```

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/5600534/vipul-rajan I have modified the question. I have to run this code on folder having 700 avro files and need to grep one unique id fro that AVRO file and get the name of the avro where this ID exists. Can you help me out here where I need to change my code as when I am trying to run the above code I am not getting the file name instead getting the path like /xyz/*.avro this I am getting.

Comment: can you please help me with the answer @vipul-ranjan